# Scala functional programming dry run

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

Could you please help me in understanding the following method:

```
def extractGlobalID(custDimIndex :Int)(gaData:DataFrame) : DataFrame = {
  val getGlobId = udf[String,Seq[GenericRowWithSchema]](genArr => {
    val globId: List[String] =
      genArr.toList
        .filter(_(0) == custDimIndex)
         .map(custDim => custDim(1).toString)

    globId match {
      case Nil => ""
      case x :: _ => x
    }
  })

  gaData.withColumn("globalId", getGlobId('customDimensions))
}
```

Comment: What do you want to know about it?

Comment: Is it just me or is this rather poor code? Surely `collectFirst` followed by `fold` would be cleaner and faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method applies an UDF to to dataframe. The UDF seems intended to extract a single ID from column of type `array<struct>`, where the first element of the struct is an index, the second one an ID.

You could rewrite the code to be more readable:

```
def extractGlobalID(custDimIndex :Int)(gaData:DataFrame) : DataFrame = {
  val getGlobId = udf((genArr : Seq[Row]) => {
    genArr
      .find(_(0) == custDimIndex)
      .map(_(1).toString)
      .getOrElse("")
  })

  gaData.withColumn("globalId", getGlobId('customDimensions))
}
```

or even shorter with `collectFirst`:

```
def extractGlobalID(custDimIndex :Int)(gaData:DataFrame) : DataFrame = {
  val getGlobId = udf((genArr : Seq[Row]) => {
    genArr
      .collectFirst{case r if(r.getInt(0)==custDimIndex) => r.getString(1)}     
      .getOrElse("")
  })

  gaData.withColumn("globalId", getGlobId('customDimensions))
}
```

Comment: @Jay1991 if this solved your problem, you may accept it - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).